# How can I make my TextField look like the following (FLUTTER)

Tags: flutter, textfield

So in my Design, I have my Textfields like this:
[image]

how can I make that in Flutter?

Comment: Can you include what you've tried so far

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Which problem do you face?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn’t know the correct size and colors so change them based on your design, if you wish you can use your icon asset instead of Icons class.

```
     @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.pink.shade50,
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: width * 0.8,
          height: height * 0.07,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(width * 0.03),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
              color: Colors.white,
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey)),
          child: Center(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                const Icon(
                  Icons.email,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: width * 0.04,
                ),
                const Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
                        hintText: 'abc@email.com',
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: I think he's asking about the border less text field or something

Comment: @mishalhaneef the code I provided is borderless because of `InputDecoration.collapsed()`

Comment: oh okay sorry i didn't notice that,

Answer (score 1):

if you mean border less textfield , then you can easily change the color of the border same as background color,

or else follow this code

```
TextFormField(
    cursorColor: Colors.black,
    keyboardType: inputType,
    decoration: new InputDecoration(
        border: InputBorder.none,
        focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
        enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
        errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
        disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
        contentPadding:
            EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, bottom: 11, top: 11, right: 15),
        hintText: "abc@gmail.com"),
  )
```